# Change name at file in NSHomeDirectory

Tags: ios, arrays, cocoa-touch, home-directory

In my app, I store some image in NSHomeDirectory in this way:

```
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"Documents/" stringByAppendingString:fileName]];
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
```

I want to rename these file when I delete one of them

example:

I have in this directory

Photo1-Photo2-Photo3 the if I delete Photo 2 I want to rename Photo3 in Photo 2

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:` method of a `NSFileManager` like so:

```
NSString *jpgPathOne = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"Documents/" stringByAppendingString:@"Photo1.jpg"]];
NSString *jpgPathTwo = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"Documents/" stringByAppendingString:@"Photo2.jpg"]];
NSString *jpgPathThree = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"Documents/" stringByAppendingString:@"Photo3.jpg"]];

NSFileManager *localFileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
// ... delete Photo2
NSError *deleteError = nil;
BOOL deleted = [localFileManager removeItemAtPath:jpgPathTwo error:&deleteError];
if (!deleted || deleteError) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR Deleting file: %@\n%@ - %@", jpgPathTwo, [deleteError localizedDescription], [deleteError localizedFailureReason]);
} else {
    // ... If delete worked, rename Photo3 to Photo2...
    NSError *renameError = nil;
    BOOL renamed = [localFileManager moveItemAtPath:jpgPathThree toPath:jpgPathTwo error:&renameError];
    if (!renamed || renameError) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR Moving file: %@ to %@!\n%@ - %@", jpgPathThree, jpgPathTwo, [renameError localizedDescription], [renameError localizedFailureReason]);
    }
}
[localFileManager release];
```

---

This is untested, but it should work:

```
- (BOOL)deleteAndRename:(NSString *)filePath {
    BOOL success = NO;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
        if (success) {
            error = nil;
            NSString *prevFilePath = filePath;
            NSString *photoNumber = [[filePath stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Photo" withString:@""];
            NSString *nextSequentialFile = [filePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:photoNumber withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([photoNumber intValue] + 1)] options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSRangeFromString(filePath)];
            BOOL moveSuccess = NO;
            while ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:nextSequentialFile]) {
                moveSuccess = [fileManager moveItemAtPath:nextSequentialFile toPath:prevFilePath error:&error];
                if (moveSuccess) {
                    prevFilePath = nextSequentialFile;
                    photoNumber = [[prevFilePath stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Photo" withString:@""];
                    nextSequentialFile = [prevFilePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:photoNumber withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([photoNumber intValue] + 1)] options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSRangeFromString(prevFilePath)];
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"*** Error Moving File: %@ -> %@ ***", nextSequentialFile, filePath);
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
                    }
                    success = NO; 
                    break;
                }
            }
            success = moveSuccess;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"*** Error Deleting File: %@ ***", filePath);
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"*** No such file: %@ ***", filePath);
        success = NO;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: it's ok but it's only for three photo, but for a dynamic situation?

Comment: there is a problem; if I have Phot1 Photo2 Photo3 Photo4 Photo5 and I delete Photo2, it rename Phot3 to Photo2 but Photo4 and Photo5? these also must change the names.

Comment: I have problem here: NSString *nextSequentialFile = [filePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:photoNumber withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([photoNumber intValue]+1)] options:NSBackwardsSearch range:[filePath rangeOfString:photoNumber options:NSBackwardsSearch]]; //it say that Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:]: Range or index out of bounds'

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example, you seem to be trying to store the order of the photos. While you could try enumerating the directory and check which files need to be changed and then change them, It would probably be much easier to maintain the index of the images using a plist and read the mutable array object from it and delete the indexes that need to be deleted and their respective images. The order will be retained after deletion.